# Creating a program to display book objects

Tags: c++

So the purpose of this program is to take book and author classes to display the Title, the author, the number of pages in each book, and the price of each book using the displayBooks method. Having a problem figuring out how this should work. Please, any suggestions?

```
class Book
{
private:

string title;

int pages;

double price;

public:
Book();

Book(string title, int pages, double price);

};
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include "Author.h"

Author::Author()
{

}

Book::Book()
{
}

Book::Book(string title, int pages, double price)
{

}

class Author
{
private:

string name;

string address;


public:
Author();

Author(string name, string address);

int getName();
int getAddress();
};

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Author.h"


Author::Author()
{
}

Author::Author(string name, string address)
{


}

int Author::getName()
{
return name;
}

int Author::getAddress()
{
return address;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Author.h"
using namespace std;

// The displayBooks function
// Purpose: Display all of the data about a book
// Parameters: A vector of Book objects
// Returns: none
void displayBooks(const vector<Book>&);

int main()
{

// create a vector for storing the account objects
vector<Book> myBooks;

// create three Author objects
Author p1("J.K.Rowling", "Edinburgh, Scotland");
Author p2("Suzanne Collins", "Connecticut, USA");
Author p3("J.R.R. Tolkien", "Bournmouth, England");

// Create three Book objects
Book b1(p1, "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", 256, 24.95);
Book b2(p2, "Mockingjay", 400, 12.99);
Book b3(p3, "The Hobbit",  322, 14.29);

// add the books to the vector
myBooks.push_back(b1 );
myBooks.push_back(b2);
myBooks.push_back(b3);

// call the displayBooks function to display the books
displayBooks(myBooks);
cout << "\n\n";

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void displayBooks(const vector<Book>& books)
{
cout << " " << mybooks << endl;
}
```

Comment: So I think I have mostly resolved the issues, still getting three errors:

Error C2065 'Book': undeclared identifier;

Error C2923 'std::vector': 'Book' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty';

Error C3203 'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type

Comment: I don't understand how your code is organized. What's in Book.h? What's in Author.h? Please post your code in distinct code sections, one for each file.